# How to understand the output of following integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, output

If one tries to evaluate the following integral,

```
Integrate[(u Cos[k])/(
4 \[Pi] (u^2/16 + (-\[CapitalLambda] + Sin[k])^2)), {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

one gets following output

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

What does this really mean?

The correct answer is 0 which is at the last with True written on the right. Also it is interesting to note that Mathematica gives 0 if one tries

```
Integrate[(u Cos[k])/(4 \[Pi] (u^2/16 + (-\[CapitalLambda] + Sin[k])^2)), {k, -\[Pi], \[Epsilon]}] +
Integrate[(u Cos[k])/(4 \[Pi] (u^2/16 + (-\[CapitalLambda] + Sin[k])^2)), {k, \[Epsilon], \[Pi]}].
```

Now, if I replace the Cos[k] with Cos[k]^2 in the numerator, i.e.

```
Integrate[(u Cos[k]^2)/(
4 \[Pi] (u^2/16 + (-\[CapitalLambda] + Sin[k])^2)), {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

the output is similar to attached picture. How do I even know what is the right answer?

Also, what is the reason for such format of output?

Comment: It is a `ConditionalExpression`. Just do `InputForm` on it to see that. It basically says there are more than one answer depending on the conditions given.

Answer (score 1):

The result of

```
j=Integrate[(u Cos[k])/(4 \[Pi] (u^2/16 + (-\[CapitalLambda] + Sin[k])^2)), {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

has a complicated form due to two complex-valued parameters. In fact, this is zero as

```
Plot3D[j,{u,0,1},{\[CapitalLambda],-2,2}]
```

[image]

and

```
ComplexPlot3D[j /. u -> 1, {\[CapitalLambda], -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}]
```

[image]

show.

Comment: `j` is a conditional expression of such a form `Piecewise[{{Huge expression, Impossible condition},{0,True}}]`.